# How to make NSView draggable in Swift (OSX Mac app)?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to make two NSView's draggable and I was wondering how to code that in Swift for OSX Mac app? I'm thinking to put two NSView's within an NSView and make them draggable within that NSView. For example, create NSViewA and nested within in are NSViewB and NSViewC (both draggable within NSViewA). I would like to code in Swift. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

You can do this fairly easily if you take advantage of the information passed on the responder chain. Consider this custom NSView class.

```
class DraggableView : NSView {
    var startPoint: NSPoint?
    var frameOrigin: NSPoint?
    
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        startPoint = event.locationInWindow
        frameOrigin = frame.origin
    }
    
    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let offset = event.locationInWindow - startPoint!
        
        frame.origin = frameOrigin! + offset
    }
    
    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        startPoint = nil
        frameOrigin = nil
    }
}
```

To make the math work for NSPoint, I overloaded operators in the extension:

```
extension NSPoint {
    static func -(pointA: NSPoint, pointB: NSPoint) -> NSPoint {
        return NSPoint(x: pointA.x - pointB.x, y: pointA.y - pointB.y)
    }
    
    static func +(pointA: NSPoint, pointB: NSPoint) -> NSPoint {
        return NSPoint(x: pointA.x + pointB.x, y: pointA.y + pointB.y)
    }
}
```

Then your ViewController class is just setup code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    let viewA: DraggableView = DraggableView()
    let viewB: DraggableView = DraggableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewA.frame = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: NSSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        viewB.frame = NSRect(origin: NSPoint(x: 125, y: 0), size: NSSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        
        viewA.wantsLayer = true
        viewB.wantsLayer = true
        
        viewA.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        viewB.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        
        view.addSubview(viewA)
        view.addSubview(viewB)
    }
}
```